# How to upload images after cropping in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, crop, image-upload

I am using `ImageCropper` and `MediaPlugin` to Upload images. However I have problem getting the image after cropping the image.

```
string imagefile;
protected void OnClickedRectangle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new ImageCropper()
    {
        Success = (imageFile) =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                view_imageavatar.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);

            });
        }
    }.Show(this);
}

async void edit_avatar_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        new ImageCropper()
        {
            PageTitle = "Title",
            AspectRatioX = 1,
            AspectRatioY = 1,
            CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
            SelectSourceTitle = "Img",
            TakePhotoTitle = "Take Camera",
            PhotoLibraryTitle = "Img Gallery",
            Success = (imageFile) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
                {
                    view_imageavatar.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    imagefile = imageFile;
                    //API Get Images Upload
                    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    content.Add(new StreamContent(imageFile), "files", imagefile);
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    var responses = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://xxxxx/api/Upload", content);
                });
            }
        }.Show(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GalleryException:>" + ex);
    }
}
```

[image]

However how can I get the Image to upload. note that `view_imageavatar` still shows the image after cropping. Tks!

**Update...**

```
async void edit_avatar_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        new ImageCropper()
        {
            PageTitle = "Title",
            AspectRatioX = 1,
            AspectRatioY = 1,
            CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
            SelectSourceTitle = "Img",
            TakePhotoTitle = "Take Camera",
            PhotoLibraryTitle = "Img Gallery",
            Success = (imageFile) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
                {
                    view_imageavatar.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    imagefile = imageFile;
                    //API Get Images Upload
                    
                    var fileStream = File.OpenRead(imageFile);
                    var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

                    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    content.Add(fileContent, "files", imageFile);
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient();    
                    
                    var responses = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://xxxxxx/api/UploadAvatarUs", content);   
                });
            }
        }.Show(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GalleryException:>" + ex);
    }
}
```

It still doesn't work?

**Update 2**

```
async void edit_avatar_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
        new ImageCropper()
        {
            PageTitle = "Title",
            AspectRatioX = 1,
            AspectRatioY = 1,
            CropShape = ImageCropper.CropShapeType.Rectangle,
            SelectSourceTitle = "Img",
            TakePhotoTitle = "Take Camera",
            PhotoLibraryTitle = "Img Gallery",
            Success = (imageFile) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
                {
                    view_imageavatar.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
                    imagefile = imageFile;
                    //API Get Images Upload

                    var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imageFile);
                    var ms = new MemoryStream(upfilebytes);
                    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    content.Add(new StreamContent(ms), "files", imageFile);


                    var httpClient = new HttpClient();    

                    var responses = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://xxxxxx/api/UploadAvatarUs", content);   
                });
            }
        }.Show(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GalleryException:>" + ex);
    }
}
```

-> **It still can't upload photos through the API?**

However I try not to use ImageCropper. I upload directly.

```
async void edit_avatar_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(await file.OpenReadAsync()), "files", file.FileName);

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var responses = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://xxxxxx/api/UploadAvatarUs", content);
    string a = responses.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

--> **Then it works fine, the image is uploaded through the API**

Does the image load from `content.Add(new StreamContent(ms), "files", imageFile);` it doesn't work with API? Looking for solutions from everyone.

Comment: You can try to new a MemoryStream such as 
{var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imageFile);
var ms = new MemoryStream(upfilebytes);
content.Add(new StreamContent(ms), "files", imageFile);}

Comment: Thank you, but that for me it still doesn't work. I updated the above in **Update 2**. You can try it.

Comment: I find where the problem is. In your code, the imageFile just is an object(or a string), not a file when your use a ImageCropper. So when you try to convert it to a stream which the content needs, you will fail and the stream don't contain the image. If you want to post the image after cropping, you can save it to the device and post it by its path.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually checked what StreamContent takes as arguments?

It takes a `Stream` not a path to a file.

You need to open the file first like so:

```
using var fileStream = File.Open(imageFile);
using var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
```

Have you tried something like that?

Comment: Thank you. However `File.Open(imageFile);` -> `Open` doesn't work. I pass in `File.OpenRead(imageFile)`. Is this good? I have updated the above.